# Translate a simple SQL Group to LINQ (how to?)

Tags: sql, linq

After studying LINQ a bit I think I am still making mistakes.
This particular simple SQL statement:

```
select APPL_COMPONENT_ID, TTEXT, count(*), count(distinct [USER])
from abi.dbo.data
where TASK='D' and [TCODE] <> 'SESSION_MANAGER'
group by APPL_COMPONENT_ID, TTEXT
order by APPL_COMPONENT_ID
```

I think translates to this LINQ:

```
var treeData =
            (from d in filteredQuery
             let groupColumns = new
             {
                 appCompId = d.APPL_COMPONENT_ID,
                 tText = d.TTEXT
             }
             where 
                String.Compare(d.TASK, "D") == 0
                && String.Compare(d.TCODE,"SESSION_MANAGER") != 0
             group d by groupColumns into gcs
             select new
             {
                 appCompId = gcs.Key.appCompId,
                 gcs.Key.tText,
                 noOfTransactions = gcs.Count(),
                 noOfUsers = gcs.Select(d => d.USER).Distinct().Count()
             }).OrderBy(d => d.appCompId);
```

But the generated SQL (by through LINQ) is far slower (400% slower).
Upon inspection on debug, it looked something like this:

```
SELECT [t4].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] AS [appCompId], [t4].[TTEXT] AS [tText], [t4].[value] AS [noOfTransactions], [t4].[value2] AS [noOfUsers]
FROM (
SELECT [t1].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID], [t1].[TTEXT], [t1].[value], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[USER]
        FROM abi.[dbo].[data] AS [t2]
        WHERE 
        (
            (
                ([t1].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NULL)
            ) 
            OR 
            (
                ([t1].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NOT NULL) 
                AND ([t2].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NOT NULL) 
                AND 
                (
                    (([t1].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NULL) 
                    AND ([t2].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NULL)) 
                    OR 
                    (
                        ([t1].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NOT NULL) 
                        AND ([t2].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] IS NOT NULL) 
                        AND ([t1].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID] = [t2].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID])
                    )
                )
            )
        ) 
        AND 
        (
            (
                ([t1].[TTEXT] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[TTEXT] IS NULL)
            ) 
            OR 
            (
                ([t1].[TTEXT] IS NOT NULL) 
                AND ([t2].[TTEXT] IS NOT NULL) 
                AND 
                (
                    (([t1].[TTEXT] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[TTEXT] IS NULL)) 
                    OR 
                    (
                        ([t1].[TTEXT] IS NOT NULL) 
                        AND ([t2].[TTEXT] IS NOT NULL) 
                        AND ([t1].[TTEXT] = [t2].[TTEXT])
                    )
                )
            )
        ) AND ([t2].[TASK] = 'D') AND ([t2].[TCODE] <> 'SESSION_MANAGER')
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [value2]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID], [t0].[TTEXT]
    FROM abi.[dbo].[data] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[TASK] = 'D') AND ([t0].[TCODE] <> 'SESSION_MANAGER')
    GROUP BY [t0].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID], [t0].[TTEXT]
    ) AS [t1]
) AS [t4]
ORDER BY [t4].[APPL_COMPONENT_ID]
```

Does anyone know to point out my mistake?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the query as:

```
        var treeData = filteredQuery
            .Where(d => d.TASK.Equals("D"))
            .Where(d => !d.TCODE.Equals("SESSION_MANAGER"))
            .GroupBy(d => new { Component = d.APPL_COMPONENT_ID, Text = d.TTEXT })
            .Select(grp => new
            {
                appCompId = grp.Key.Component,
                tText = grp.Key.Text,
                noOfTransactions = grp.Count(),
                noOfUsers = grp.Select(d => d.USER).Distinct().Count()
            }).OrderBy(results => results.appCompId);
```

Comment: I gave it a try, and the generated SQL seemed the same, the query time is the same, 21s, about 400% more. This means the query is not equivalent even with SQL optimizations.
So, this did not do the trick. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this *trick*.
I know it doesn't offer the same mechanics as the desired LINQ solution. But it delivers the same result in much less time (<1 s).
The problem was split in 2 parts:

1. LINQ without grouping.
2. Grouping done in memory using dictionaries.

That is:

1. The LINQ:

   ```
       var treeData = (
               from d in filteredQuery
               where d.TASK == "D"
               where d.TCODE != "SESSION_MANAGER"
               select new
               {
                   d.APPL_COMPONENT_ID,
                   d.TTEXT,
                   d.USER
               }
           );
       var dataList = treeData.ToList();
   ```
2. The grouping:

   ```
       Dictionary<String, DataNode> data = new Dictionary<String, DataNode>();
       foreach (var d in dataList)
       {
           //aggregation in Dictionary based on your data model
           ...
       }
   ```

Note: in the end this solution was **much faster**. It remained the desired solution.So, I guess, thanks to the limitations of LINQ that this optimization over time was found.